# How can I get just numbers in a field parsed to another field?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to parse just the numbers from a field into a new field assuming data similar to the following using PLSQL?

```
RESERVE35%,
RESERVE10%,
RESERVE5%,
NONE,
FIRST,
LAST,
RESERVE75%
```

I'm envisioning the following in a new field

```
35,
10,
5,
null,
null,
null,
75
```

Comment: Will there be at most one sequence of consecutive digits? If there can be more than one, what is the desired handling? Also, are the numbers always positive integers, or can they be negative and/or have decimal point (or other decimal separator)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; regular expressions help:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    ( select 'RESERVE35%' from dual union all
  3      select 'RESERVE10%' from dual union all
  4      select 'RESERVE5%' from dual union all
  5      select 'NONE' from dual union all
  6      select 'FIRST' from dual union all
  7      select 'LAST' from dual union all
  8      select 'RESERVE75%' from dual
  9    )
 10  select col,
 11    regexp_substr(col, '\d+') result
 12  from test;

COL        RESULT
---------- ----------------------------------------
RESERVE35% 35
RESERVE10% 10
RESERVE5%  5
NONE
FIRST
LAST
RESERVE75% 75

7 rows selected.
```